# Sodium chloride + sulfuric acid

Tags: acid-base

Why does sulfuric acid displace more volatile acids from salts?
My textbook says that sulfuric acid can displace more volatile acids from metal salts.
How is $\ce{HCl}$, which is not even a reactant, 'displaced' from $\ce{NaCl}$, as there is no $\ce{HCl}$ to be displaced?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50656/how-is-volatility-useful-in-the-production-of-acids

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is $\ce{HCl}$, which is not even a reactant, 'displaced' from
>   $\ce{NaCl}$, as there is no $\ce{HCl}$ to be displaced?

Well, there will be some $\ce{HCl}$ due to a well-known chemical reaction which is used both in the lab as well as in production to get the hydrogen chloride:

$$\ce{NaCl(s) + H2SO4(s) → NaHSO4(s) + HCl(g)}$$

The reaction proceeds at room temperature, but note, that the reagents should be dry. If you heat it up above 200 °C reaction proceeds even further:

$$\ce{NaCl(s) + NaHSO4(s) → HCl(g) + Na2SO4(s)}$$

Hydrochloric acid is then prepared by dissolving hydrogen chloride in water.