# How to compare volatility of inorganic acids

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Extending [This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50656/how-is-volatility-useful-in-the-production-of-acids) question further

> Sulfuric acid because of its low volatility can be used to manufacture more volatile acids from their corresponding salts

To use this statement in practice I need to compare the volatility of the acids. My book states that using this principle above $\ce{HF, HCl, HNO3}$ can be formed as some examples.

I wish to ask how can I compare the volatility of inorganic acid without being provided the data. Is there any reliable method to do so? I see sometimes hydrogen bonding being used for this purpose but are there any more methods which cover a wider range of molecules ?

Comment: You will realize that in chemistry, it is usually much, Much, MUCH easier to grab particular experimental data than to make quantitative theoretical predictions from basic general principles. You can later apply some recognized behaviour patterns, but it is very rough estimation with many exceptions and outliers.